# After update Android Studio getting MainActivity is not assignable to android.app.activity error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Upgraded old android studio to Android Studio 3.4.1, when open old one of my project for updation getting mainactivity is not assignable error. tried some ways not usable.

Mainfest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pdroid.tamil.firstnite"
android:versionCode="6"
android:versionName="6" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     </application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.appodeal.ads.Appodeal;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private TextView brief_desc_txt;
private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait story has been loading...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    brief_desc_txt = (TextView)findViewById(com.pdroid.tamil.firstnite.R.id.txt3);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/tscmaduram.ttf");
    brief_desc_txt.setTypeface(typeface);
    brief_desc_txt.setText(UnocideUtil.unicode2tsc(readTxt()));

    }

private String readTxt(){
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(com.pdroid.tamil.firstnite.R.raw.story);
    System.out.println(inputStream);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;

    try{
        i=inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1)
        {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i=inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
}
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.6.2.jar')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

When in to compiling getting error MainActivity is not assignable to android.app.Activity also getting error in MainActivity.java related to ActionBarActivity (cannot resolve the symbol)

any one see this.

Comment: Are you using AndroidX?

Comment: no, using mobile with android 7

Comment: Can you please show us some of your XML code?